# Perl and epoch time question

Tags: perl, datestamp

How can I take the current epoch time from perl and find the epoch time from 6 months ago?

I need to compare the create date of a file to see if it 6 months or older.

Comment: How is the difference between two numbers calculated? How can X seconds (or milliseconds, etc) be converted into days (or months)? (To be 100% accurate you'd need a Date module that understands leap-days and whatnot. However, for "6 months", basic math is A-OK.)

Comment: I just need a rough calculation, does not need nano seconds and what not. I just need to see if the file is older than 6 months, if it is we delete it.

Comment: @pst: For "a week" or "N days", basic math is OK, but the number of days in six months varies depending on the start/end date.

Comment: POSIX files don’t have create dates.

Comment: @Dave Sherohman "30.5 days" ;-)

Answer (score 4):

The difference can be calculated using [`DateTime`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DateTime):

```
use DateTime;

my $dt = DateTime->now;  # or if you have epoch: DateTime->from_epoch( 'epoch' => $epoch );
$dt->subtract( DateTime::Duration->new( 'months' => 6 ) );
```

Comment: Oo I like that solution, do you happen to know if DateTime is a core module?

Comment: _[Solignis](http://stackoverflow.com/users/386901/solignis)_: `DateTime` is not a core module. You can check if a module is in core using `corelist`. Example: `corelist DateTime`.

Comment: _[Solignis](http://stackoverflow.com/users/386901/solignis)_: You are welcome. :-)

Answer (score 1):

The [Date::Calc](http://search.cpan.org/~stbey/Date-Calc-6.3/lib/Date/Calc.pod) package has functions for that. Use Date_to_Time and Time_to_Date to convert to/from epoch time, and use Add_Delta_YM to add -6 months.

Comment: Bah! I cannot get that module on Windows.

Comment: Depending on how much error you can tolerate, you can compute epoch time minus six months by subtracting (365 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 500) from now. (Those should probably be long values.) The 500 (instead of 1000) at the end is for half a year instead of a full year. This is likely to be off by a day or two.

Answer (score 0):

Rough and ready?

```
perl -le '$sixm = 30.5*6; for ( glob("*") ) { print "delete $_" if -M > $sixm }'
```